# Is this possible in JavaScript promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, synchronization

I am trying to produce using JavaScript promises.

> x = {a : 5}

Example:

```
new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(5);
    }, 2000)
}).then(v => {
    x = {
        a: v
    };
    console.log(x);
})
```

**BUT**, I want to learn how can I achieve the same using this code:

```
x = {
    a: new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(5);
        }, 2000)
    })
};
```

Please guide. I shall be in debt.

Comment: You are probably looking for the [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/await combination. In your code `a` property is a promise object and not the promise's resolved value.

Comment: `I want to learn how can I achieve the same using this code` not possible at all - a Promise is a Promise, it never changes to anything else ... like `5` ... it's `5`, it can't turn into `"Hello world"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not possible with promises.

It appears you're fairly misguided about what a promise is or how it works. A promise is an object that will eventually contain some future value and it contains a method `.then(fn)` by which you can register a callback to be called when the future value is available or if an error occurs in trying to obtain that value.

But, the promise does not "become" that future value - it always remains a promise object. So, you cannot do what you show the way you show it.  Promises do not turn into their resolved values.  They store the resolved value internally so that they can notify registered `.then()` handlers when the value becomes available (or if there are errors trying to obtain the value).

Since it isn't clear what the real world problem is that you're actually trying to solve, I'm not sure what code to recommend, but it is clear that you cannot do what you're trying to do.

> I want to learn how can I achieve the same using this code

It is simply not possible with that code.  That is not how promises work.

---

You could create a function that would eventually set the `x.a` property to `5` when a promise was resolved though I'm not sure why you don't just code that directly in the promise's `.then()` handler (as I said, I don't see what real world problem you're trying to solve here).

```
// set obj[prop] to the resolved value of the promise p
function setProp(p, obj, prop) { 
    return p.then(function(val) {
       obj[prop] = val;
    });
}

let x = {};
let p = new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(5);
    }, 2000); 
});

setProp(p, x, "a").then(function() {
    console.log(x);
});
```